# Which is (if any) the generic fastest method to perform modular exponentiation?

Tags: multiplication, modular-arithmetic

After a bit of surfing, I have found that [Schönhage–Strassen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm) (without taking in consideration recent optimizations) seems to be the base algorithm to perform the requested operation. Anyways, this algorithm is focused on "raw" multiplication of two integers $a$ and $b$, if a sufficiently large $N$ is chosen (the multiplication is modulus $2^N+1$.

A first question would be: how is this algorithm abstracted to perform exponentiation?

Say, we want to perform $$c^k \pmod{n},$$ how we proceed?
A naive approach would be to use the Schönhage–Strassen with $a = c$, $b = c$ and $N$ such that $2^N+1 = n$, as many times as needed (in this case, $k-1$ times). Am I in the good direction? If not, how does it works? Is this algorithm the best one yet known?

Comment: You should look at [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Comment: Wikipedia has an article on this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation.

Comment: @Nathaniel Yeah, I saw it. But I was more curious about performing modular exponentiation by using the fast fourier transform as some exponentiation algorithms implement it.

Answer (score 1):

The standard method is exponentiation by repeated squaring: To calculate say x^11 modulo p, you start with x modulo p, then calculate x^2 modulo p, x^4 modulo p, x^5 modulo p, x^10 modulo p, x^11 modulo p. You won't get anything asymptotically faster than this.

For fixed exponents, you can find methods that take slightly fewer multiplications, but finding the right way will be very expensive, and this will only be worthwhile for smallish exponents that are used a lot.

You can save some multiplications if x is small compared to p. Let's say x^15 < p, and you want to calculate x^255 modulo p. The normal method takes 14 multiplications. But we can calculate x^15 without any modular operations. Then instead of exponents 30, 31, 62, 63, 126, 127, 254, 255 we square five times to get exponents 30, 60, 120, 240 then multiply by x^15 modulo p. It's not asymptotically faster, but maybe 30 or 40% faster. For situations like a probabilistic primality test with small numbers to be exponentiated to huge exponenets this is quite useful.

Calculating (a * b) modulo p correctly may be time consuming; it may be significantly quicker to calculate (a * b) modulo p, plus some small multiple of p. Let reduce (a, b, p) be (a * b) modulo p + k*p for some small unknown k. If you can show that for a, b < x (put possible >= p) reduce (a, b, x) produces a result less than x, in a shorter time than needed for (a * b) modulo p, then the whole exponentiation can be performed faster using the "reduce" function instead of modulo. Only the final result must be forced into the range from 0 to p-1. This can again bring significant percents in savings.

And obviously you should check whether a^2 modulo p can be found sligtly faster than a general (a*b) modulo p.

PS. Didn't notice your requirement that the modulus is $2^N + 1$. This will make the calculation a lot easier.